# bulk conversion of gis points into lat/long

Tags: php, mysql, database, gis, latitude-longitude

I've a db of thousand of records, each records contains a couple of coordinates in GIS format.
I need to convert -just once- all those points into lat/long points.

how can i achieve that?

- php?
- mysql?-->sql
- scripting?

i've manually tried this one [online gis converter](https://www.fcc.gov/media/radio/dms-decimal)
but with the first couple of datas gis: 
lat_gis: 40°29'02,70''  long_gis: 16°28'60,00'' 
give an error about seconds thats must be less than 60 (<60)
are the initial data wrong?

wich is the  smarter and fastes way?

Comment: What does the `70` in `40°29'02,70` mean?

Comment: in the italian decimal format "," are like "." so are decimal of seconds, if they have sense in this case

Comment: @JayBlanchard: This question is about converting degrees-minutes-seconds to decimal figures. [The question you marked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939837/gis-spatial-functions-in-php) is about GIS geographic projection conversion. This question is certainly not a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 2):

You'd probably need a string conversion function like this:

```php
<?php

function gis2dec(string $string): string {
    $string = str_replace(',', '.', $string);
    if (preg_match('#^((\d+(\.\d+|))°)((\d+(\.\d+|))(′|\')|)((\d+(\.\d+|))(″|"|′′|\'\')|)(|\s*([NESW]))$#', $string, $matches)) {
        $sign = 1;
        switch (strtoupper($matches[13])) {
            case 'S':
            case 'W':
                $sign = -1;
                break;
        }
        return $sign * ($matches[2] + ((float) ($matches[5] ?? 0)) / 60 + ((float) ($matches[9] ?? 0)) / 3600);
    }
    return (string) $string;
}

var_dump(gis2dec("40°29'02,70''"));
var_dump(gis2dec("16°28'60,00''"));
var_dump(gis2dec("40°29'02,70'' S"));
var_dump(gis2dec("16°28'60,00'' W"));
```

Output:

```
string(15) "40.484083333333"
string(15) "16.483333333333"
string(16) "-40.484083333333"
string(16) "-16.483333333333"
```

Comment: why did u set a fixed offset of "13"?

Comment: 13 is the subgroup of my regular expression that matches the N / E / S / W sector. If it is South or West, the coordinate needs to be converted to negative for map service like Google Maps to work.

Comment: Just `var_dump` the `$matches` after the `preg_match` call to see what's in it.